# Python setattr() can't find attribute that obviously exists

Tags: python, setattribute, setattr

I'm at my wits end.
Can't find anything else that helps with this.

```
dta = {'type': "", 'content': ""}
print dta
```

> `>>>{'content': '', 'type': ''}`

```
setattr(dta, 'type', "Steve")
```

> `>>>AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'type'`

Comment: If you can't do `dta.type`, then you should not be able to set it with `setattr`.

Comment: Keys stored in a dictionary aren't the same thing as _attributes_.

Comment: A dict's keys aren't attributes. But it's easy to make an object whose attributes can be accessed with index syntax as well as attribute syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python's dictionaries aren't JS objects. When you create a dict, you aren't creating a dynamic object whose properties you can change at runtime as in JS. Instead the dictionary knows how to store pairs of keys and values and does so by overriding the operator [] (`def __getitem__(self, key)`).

On a more implementation level - calling `getattr` / `setattr` is really a shorthand for `data.__getattr__("foo")` and since `dict` uses `__getitem__` as opposed to `__getattr__` the function call fails.

Thus, there's no way to set (or get for that matter) the dict's items using generic attribute functions.

*However*, you can create your custom dict class that does support that operation (although I wouldn't recommend it):

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        dict.__init__(self)

    # Override getattr and setattr so that they return the values of getitem / setitem
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]

data = AttrDict()
data["foo"] = "bar"
print(getattr(data, "foo"))
```

Comment: I completely don't understand you.  I'm doing this in the python console.  setattr() is a standard Python library function built specifically to change values of dictionalry attributes.

Comment: No it isn't. `setattr` is a built-in function specifically to change values of *object attributes*, not dictionary values.

Comment: Got ya. OBJECT is not a DICT.  And I probably confusing my JS work (syntax) with the Python code I'm always writing at the same time

Comment: @Steve Exactly! See my edit for some further explanations.

Answer (score 6):

`setattr` does not work with a dictionary because it does not have an `__dict__`.

I can make a simple class and instance:

```
In [88]: class Obj(object):
    ...:     pass
    ...: 
In [89]: ob = Obj()
In [90]: ob.__dict__
Out[90]: {}
In [91]: setattr(ob,'test',34)
In [92]: ob.__dict__
Out[92]: {'test': 34}
In [95]: ob.test
Out[95]: 34
```

`setattr` sets an item in the `__dict__` of `obj`, and the resulting attribute can be accessed with `.test` syntax.

But a `dict` object does not have a `__dict__`.

```
In [96]: dd={1:2, 3:4}
In [97]: dd.__dict__
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__dict__'

In [98]: setattr(dd, 'test', 34)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'test'
```

I add items to the dict with the dictionary indexing notation:

```
In [99]: dd['test'] = 34
In [100]: dd
Out[100]: {1: 2, 3: 4, 'test': 34}
```

The dictionary class inherits from `object`, but in way that does not give each instance a `__dict__`.  Thus `setattr` has nothing to act on.

If for some reason the `[]=` syntax is awkward, you can use `operator.setitem` as a function:

```
In [108]: operator.setitem?
Docstring: setitem(a, b, c) -- Same as a[b] = c.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
In [109]: operator.setitem(dd, 'test', 23)
In [110]: dd
Out[110]: {1: 2, 3: 4, 'test': 23}
```

Or use the `__setitem__` method

```
In [111]: dd.__setitem__('test', 1)
In [112]: dd
Out[112]: {1: 2, 3: 4, 'test': 1}
```

Actually, a dictionary does have attributes.  For example its `.get` method can be fetched with `getattr`.  `setattr` returns a different error in this example.

```
In [119]: getattr(dd,'get')
Out[119]: <function dict.get>
In [120]: setattr(dd,'get',dict.get)
...
AttributeError: 'dict' object attribute 'get' is read-only
```

Without the `__dict__` we can't add an attribute to a dictionary.  And many, if not all, of the existing attributes are read only.  I don't know if a dictionary has an attributes that can be changed.

Actually a dictionary is an `object`:

```
In [121]: isinstance(dd,dict)
Out[121]: True
In [122]: isinstance(dd,object)
Out[122]: True
```

I just imported `defaultdict`.  It too lacks a `__dict__`.  But I was able to use `setattr(ddd,'default_factory', int)`.  I think that `no attribute` is the correct error message when the attribute does not already exist, and it cannot add new ones.

==============

I'd have to double check the documentation on this, but I think `setattr(dd,...)` delegates to `dd.__setattr__(...)`.

```
In [168]: dd.__setattr__('test',1)
...
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'test'

In [169]: dd.__setattr__('get',None)
...
AttributeError: 'dict' object attribute 'get' is read-only
```

So the error message is determined by the `dict` class, not `setattr`.

Even instances that have a `__dict_-` might raise errors if `setattr` is used wrong.  For example a number is not a valid attribute name:

```
In [171]: setattr(ob, 123, 'a')
....
TypeError: attribute name must be string, not 'int'
```

But `setattr` can set attributes that can't be accessed with the `.` syntax:

```
In [172]: setattr(ob, 'a#re',1)
In [174]: ob.a#re
...
AttributeError: 'Obj' object has no attribute 'a'
In [175]: getattr(ob, 'a#re')
Out[175]: 1
```

`vars()` is another way of accessing the `__dict__` of an instance:

```
In [179]: vars(dd)
 ...
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

Comment: It would be nice if `setattr(obj, attr, val)`  first did a test `if (type obj == 'dict')  throw error "'obj ' is not an object"`.  How handy would that be?

Comment: if you `s = { "qwe": "asd" }` and `print type s` you get `> > > type dict` so if you in inadvertently pass a dict (i.e. s) to setattr() but it requires an object then setattr() should test for this and throw an error that regards the absence of an object parameter value.  Instead what it does do is throw an error that it can't find the attribute in the dict that you requested.

Comment: Actually it's the dictionary `__setattr__` method that generates your error.

Comment: I don't understand why I can't do setattr(object(), "test", 1), but I can do setattr(Obj(), "test", 1") with your Obj class. The Obj() class is empty, so why can I extend it but not object()?

Comment: @Samuel  Did you try `object().__dict__`?  `Obj` class doesn't add any methods, but it still is a user defined class with a `__dict__`.

Comment: So when you extend object python implicitly adds some methods to it?

Comment: @Samuel, Looking at `__dir__`, the main addition is the `__dict__`.  That changes the behavior methods like `__setattr__`.  There must be better sources for this than my memory.  I learned Python is v2 days, and have kept up with the changes as needed.  I haven't needed to do anything fancy with classes.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots `slots` is a way of bypassing the `__dict__` creation. Lots more details on  this page. @Samuel

Answer (score 2):

You can assign dict values directly, setattr() is not needed.

```
dta = {'type': "", 'content': ""}
dta["type"] = "Steve"
```

Comment: Yeah. I know.  But I'm using setattr() successfully else where.  Consistency is important.  Any thoughts on my setattr() is failing?  .... .... while retyping this I realized 'type' is reserved word.  Could that be it?

Comment: a quick test.  The error is NOT due to 'type' being a reserved word

Comment: Setattr, cannot assign a value to a dict-key. Review docs types/classes/setattr ...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr  This is the counterpart of getattr(). The arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value. The string may name an existing attribute or a new attribute. The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it. For example, setattr(x, 'foobar', 123) is equivalent to x.foobar = 123.

Comment: Got ya.  OBJECT is not a DICT

Comment: 'The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it'

Answer (score 1):

'setattr()' refers to something else. When you write `setattr(dta, 'type', "Steve")` you're trying to access the field `dta.type`, dict class has no attribute `type`, so it gives an error.

`dict_object['key']` is a completely different thing, and it's how dict members should be accessed.

More about settatr() [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are [subscriptable](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=subscriptable#subscriptions), the key:value pairs are items instead of attributes.

Items are accessed using a subscript notation:

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> d['a']
1
```

[Attributes are accessed using dot notation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references)

```
>>> d.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    d.a
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'a'
```

operator.itemgetter is similar to getattr:

```
>>> import operator
>>> bee = operator.itemgetter('b')
>>> bee(d)
2
>>>
```

---

```
>>> hasattr(d, '__getitem__')
True
>>> hasattr(d, '__getattr__')
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

[docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)

> This is the counterpart of getattr(). The arguments are an **object**,
>   a string and an arbitrary value. The string may name an existing
>   attribute or a new attribute. The function assigns the value to the
>   attribute, provided the **object** allows it

OBJECT is not a DICTIONARY. And I probably confusing my JS work (syntax) with the Python code I'm always writing at the same time

So the error message is confusing:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'type'

It should be more like:

> 'setattr() is for objects not dictionaries'

.

Thanks everyone.